# reporting performance to the server with ajax and .net mvc 3

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http, jquery

I am building a mobile site that works like a slideshow. There are a number of image slides and you can swipe left and right to traverse the slides.

I would like to monitor the download speed performance of the slides using javascript and report the times to the server.

I presume that ajax is the way to report the times, although I am new to ajax. My fist concern is that the report sent to the server should be as lean as possible. Also it is only really necassary for the communication with the server to be one way.

Can the flow go just in the direction of from the browser to the server without any responses being sent back to the browser? Or do the http post and put methods have to send a response back to the browser? Obviously notthing is actually needed to be sent back to the browser and to the mobile site it doesn't even really matter if the request is a success or failure.

If a response does have to be sent to the browser what should my MVC 3 controller return? Can just a head with success or failure be returned?

Finally which of the http POST and PUT methods is best for this and what will be the best data format to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a POST to an action on the server. 
I would suggest you use JSON for the data as it is quite lean and makes it easy to decode. However, if you wanted to make it really lean you you could just use a parameter on the url, like ..../reportPerf?d=123 and then your action should take a parameter "d".

The server **does** need to respond, but you can just

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200)
```

That will only take a few bytes.

Sorry for the brevity, on a mobile device.